# Setting Cookie via PHP works in Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, cross-browser, setcookie

I have an issue where setting a cookie works perfectly in chrome but not IE or firefox. All the browsers are the current version and I am on a Windows 8 machine. I am trying to set a cookie which lasts for a year.

I can verify that IE and firefox are receiving other cookies from my site created by other plugins and 3rd party services but it just does not want to accept the cookie I am trying to set.

Via firebug in Firefox, I tried to view rejected cookies but none are listed and it is like my cookie just does not want to work outside of chrome.

This code is in a functions.php file inside of my wordpress website:

```
add_action( 'init', 'visitor_cookie');
function visitor_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['returning_visit'])) {
        $traffic_type = 'hd';
        $timestring = microtime();
        $pieces = explode(" ", substr($timestring, 2));
        $pieces[0] = "1".substr($pieces[0],0,3);
        $visitor_id = $traffic_type.dechex($pieces[1]) . dechex($pieces[0]);
        $expire = time()+60*60*24*360;
        $path = '/';
        $domain = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
        setcookie(
            'returning_visit', 
            $visitor_id, 
            $expire, 
            $path, 
            $domain
      );
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. As a note my domain is currently development.mydomain.com which will be moved to mydomain.com
2. This is not on a localhost/server, its at a hosting company
3. This cookie should be available across my entire website.
4. Cookie expiration date is set to one year

In addition to viewing the cookies in my browser, I was also using this code to verify the cookie which again showed output in chrome but no other browser.

```
<?php echo "'".$_COOKIE['returning_visit']."'"; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

The issue is the cookie is only set when logged in as admin. The cookie is indeed being set. I created a question more specific to wordpress:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120302/php-cookie-via-plugin-only-set-when-logged-in-as-admin-and-not-regular-user-and

**Solution**

The issue was my host caching the pages. Needed to uncache the pages for the proper php code to run. Caching was disabled for Admins, which is why I got the cookie as admin and not a normal user.

Comment: Where are you testing to see if the cookie is set? You can't test for a cookie on the same load as the one where you set it in

Comment: I am going into the settings area of the browsers to where the cookies show. I browse the website for a few pages before checking. I am also using firebug for and IE dev tools for live cookie checking. I am also using the developer tools in chrome for live preview.

Comment: please show us echos of `'returning_visit', 
            $visitor_id, 
            $expire, 
            $path, 
            $domain`
. In next I would debug HTTP headers using browser tools like firebug etc.

Comment: Might not make any difference, but add a third parameter of `1` to your `add_action` call. In one WP plugin I wrote I had to start sessions and that was the only way to ensure it worked.

Comment: @Machavity , I am new to wp plugins. What exactly do you mean? and Peter, the echos of those values appear above. The output of $visitor_id appears like hd526da66a767, chrome shows the expiration as being the same date but in 2014 and the domain chrome shows is .development.mydomain.com

Comment: check the HTTP Headers in firefox and IE. If `Cookie: xx-new-cookie-values-xx` doesn't show up check is function is really fired or not. Basically debug everything, and browser tools like firebug is first step.

Comment: What I mean is change your first line to `add_action( 'init', 'visitor_cookie', 1);`

Comment: Peter, trying to figure out exactly how to view the http headers like that. @Machavity , unfortunately that did not work. Cookies are still only created in Chrome but not any other browser.

Comment: Turns out the cookie only set for logged in admins and not regular users. I am not sure why as I have other scripts which function with a similar call that works for all users.

Comment: Firefox: use firebug, find the request (in "Net" tab), read the hedaers, other browsers: i dont know. I don't really think anyone here will help you (your code should run perfectly fine), I recommend you to do some debugging - check http headers using browser debugging tools, and **make sure this function is executed on every browser**, it might be wordpress issue etc. just do the debugging stuff as we all do

Comment: Thank you for your assistance peter. My site has other cookies but I can't find any cookie http information within the net tab of firebug. The Net tab only shows me actual calls like files which are get calls. The cookies tab is really the only place I see cookie information, but nothing similar to Cookie: xx-new-cookie-values-xx .. I will continue looking into it, so I know for future reference. Thank you again.

Comment: While I have undying love for Firebug, I actually prefer the Firefox developer tools for this. It has a menu just for managing cookies and a really awesome tool for seeing all that are set and even deleting them easily https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Comment: yeah, just before setcookie add `echo "i am trying to setcookie with arguments ...` and if everything is fine.. it might be php bug. another thing is - `setcookie` must be fired before **any output** so make sure there is no blank space in php files etc. *t I can't find any cookie http information within the net tab of firebug. Th* expand the request row and you should find tabs like "request response cookies" etc. check the "request" tab

Comment: Peter thank you, I found it :). @Machavity, thank you for the link :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i read your update

> The issue is the cookie is only set when logged in as admin. The cookie is indeed being set.

It looks like the event handler

```
add_action( 'init', 'visitor_cookie');
```

is fired only when user is an admin..

I believe on Chrome you work on admin session, on other browser you work as guest.

put the thing outside `if( is-admin )` expression

Comment: I accept your answer Peter. However I am not using any is-admin expression which is what is perplexing me. I am updating my post with another question I created. But your assistance was greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue was my host caching the pages. Needed to uncache the pages for the proper php code to run. Caching was disabled for Admins, which is why I got the cookie as admin and not a normal user.